# Spark repartition

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

What is the need of repartioning data. How to decide the repartition size in spark.

Is repartition concept applicable to spark streaming and structured streaming.

DF.repartition(num)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, partition concept is applicable to both spark streaming (RDDs) and structured streaming (structured API).

**Partitioning of the data can be used - among other things - to increase the level parallelism when applying map- and filter-type operations.**

Note, when you partition your data there will *always* incur a full shuffle regardless of whether one is necessary. This is applicable to both APIs (RDD and Structured).

Sometime, a repartition of your data avoids shuffles and improves performance as data can be changed within a partition. For example if you know that you are going to be filtering by a certain column (e.g. "country") multiple times, it can be worth repartitioning based on that column:

```scala
df.repartition(col("country"))
```

The main difference between RDD and Structured API is that only for RDDs (meaning for spark streaming) you can define your own `Partitioner` class. This gives you all flexibility on how the data is partitioned and therefore give you significant performance and stability improvement if used correctly.

Comment: Mike, how to decide num of partitions. Is this only decided with data size